# How to split an EPUB into multiple files of one chapter?

Tags: epub, chapters

An EPUB book has multiple chapters. What method to split it into multiple files, each of them consist one chapter, effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each chapter is formatted as an h1-h6 tag or marked with a unique style, you could use [Sigil](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/releases/tag/0.9.9) to insert split markers. For example, if all your chapter headings are formatted as `<h1>` tags, you'd use:

**Find:**`<h1`

**Replace:**`<hr class="sigil_split_marker" /><h1`

Then select **Edit > Split at markers**.

Comment: [How to do it if each chapter consists multiple html pages?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7629/10251)

Comment: Simply select all files in the Sigil Book Browser, then right-click them and select Merge. This will merge **all** files into a single file.  
Then use Find & Replace to add split markers and select Edit > Split at markers.

Comment: [How to have images when exporting a sub-files?](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=3639908#post3639908). Using Save As doesn't include the images.

Comment: For anyone coming here from an online search, you can also do `cmd + enter` to split at cursor position.